# Find and Label duplicate Keywords in a table in Data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have keywords from two google ad accounts displayed in a table in the data studio. I want to find the duplicates and label them as "Common keywords". I want help with finding a function or formula that will help me create this new field.

**The table I have currently:**

| Ad account | Keywords |
| --- | --- |
| Client A | clothes women |
| Client B | shirts men |
| Client A | pants boy |
| Client B | warm jeans |
| Client A | winter jacket |
| Client B | pants boy |
| Client A | gloves |
| Client B | clothes women |

**The column I want to add - Common or Unique:**

| Ad account | Keywords | Common or Unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | clothes women | Common |
| Client B | shirts men | Unique |
| Client A | pants boy | Common |
| Client B | warm jeans | Unique |
| Client A | winter jacket | Unique |
| Client B | pants boy | Common |
| Client A | gloves | Unique |
| Client B | clothes women | Common |

*Edited for more clarity

Comment: While the tables help, providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue as each data set may have aspects that are different

Answer (score 0):

Add a table with the fields `Ad account` and `Keywords` as dimensions.
Then add a field `Common` with the formula

```
case when Record Count=1 then "Unique" else "Common" end
```

and drag this new field to the matrics of the table.

[image]